# Difference between staging and production environments on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am encountering a subtle difference between my staging and production environments, which are meant to be identical.  How do make sure that they are both exactly the same and are running the same code, have the same assets loaded, running the same migrations etc.

For example, you can check that each has the same commit by running `heroku releases` and you can check each has the same database migration by running `heroku run rake db:version`. What else can you do to verify each environment is exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the places you can  look:

1. Compare `config/production.rb` and `config/staging.rb`
2. Execute `heroku config` on both production and staging and look for differences
3. Execute `heroku rake db:version` on both platforms and check for differences
4. Execute`heroku rake releases` on both platforms and make sure you have same commit.
5. Check on the heroku webconsole that you are on the same stack for both platforms
6. If you are using postgres, execute `heroku pg:info` on both platforms

You do not need to use the database related queries if it is  just a styling difference.

Comment: is there an equivalent to the `config` command outside heroku?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?  If you are asking about development or test environments, the config variables are in .env file

Answer (score 0):

You could read more in the [Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) but one thing you could try is viewing the apps config vars with `heroku config.`

Comment: is there an equivalent to the `config` command outside heroku?